# How to save user in context after login

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use function from context provider file in order to save current user info in context and pass it between components

this is my provider code :

```
class UIContext extends Component {

   state = {
       userId: "",
       userName: ""
   }

   saveUser = (id, name) => {
       this.setState({
           userId: id,
           userName: name
       })
}

   render(){
       return(
           <UserContext.Provider value={{
               state: this.state,
               saveUser: this.saveUser
           }}>
               {this.props.children}
           </UserContext.Provider>
       )
   }
}
```

this is my login page render function code :

```
 render() {
        return (
            <UserContext.Consumer>
            {({context}) => (
                <>

       <input className="main_input" onChange={this.onChangeHandlerTz} id="tz" placeholder='ID'/>
                    <input className="main_input" type="password" onChange={this.onChangeHandlerPass} id="pass" placeholder='Password'/>

                    <button className="main_btn" id="save" onClick={this.onClickLogin}>login</button>
                    <button className="main_btn" id="save" onClick={this.onClickRegister}>register</button>

            </>)}
            </UserContext.Consumer>
)}
```

I want to use this.context.saveUser here:

```
onClickLogin = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.validate(this.state.id)) {
            fetch('/api/v1/login',
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        id: this.state.id,
                        password: this.state.pass
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
                    }
                }).then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.status === 0) {
                  this.context.saveUser(this.state.id, this.state.fullName)
                    } else {
                        this.setState({loginError: true})
                    }
                }).catch(error => {
                // this.setState({loading: false})
                this.setState({error: error})
                console.log(error)
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({idError:true})
        }
    };
```

this is the error I get :

```
TypeError: _this.context.saveUser is not a function
```

how can I use the context outside the render function ?

Comment: remove the "this" keyword, context is not a class property/field but rather a parameter passed into the Lamda Function within your UserContext.Consumer. I would also suggest looking at setting up a store and reducer to create a real global state. Then look at the new hooks, namely useContext(UserContext) which lets you access the value directly without using the element <Context.Consumer> component.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you may be destructuring the wrong argument here:

```
<UserContext.Consumer>
  {({ context }) => {}}
</UserContext.Consumer>
```

Since the `value` you provided to the `UserContext.Provider` included `state` and `saveUser`, you probably want to pull those out instead of `context`:

```
{({ state, saveUser }) => {}}
```

Second, if you defined `onClickLogin` on the same component that you shared the `render` method from, you want to wrap your component in the `<UserContext.Consumer>` so that the entire component has access to `state` and `saveUser` as props. Something like this:

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  onClickLogin = () => {
    console.log(this.props.user.state)
    console.log(typeof this.props.user.saveUser)
  }
  render() {
    <button onClick={this.onClickLogin}>Login</button>
  }
}

export default props => 
  <UserContext.Consumer>
    {user => <LoginPage user={user} {...props} />}
  </UserContext.Consumer>
```